# Вопрос по scanw

Tags: c, ncurses

Что происходит при вызове `scanw("%*d");` 
Есть такой код:

```
while (!quit) {
   for(int i = 0; i < rate; i++){
      ch = getch();
      if (ch != ERR){
         for (int j = 0; j < (rate-i); j++) getch();
         break;
      }
    }
    //scanw("%*d");
```

При вызове scanw, ch на сколько я понял становится равной -1.
Мне ну нужно её использовать просто хочу понять что она делает.

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что `scanw`, а не `scanf`?...

Comment: @Harry так ведь это ncurses, делает он то де что и scanf. Но все равно - нет - я не уверен.
Хотя я просто хочу понять что он делает.

Comment: Если бы это был `scanf` - то считывал бы десятичное целое число (пропуская предваряющие пробельные символы, если таковые имеются), пока читается, останавливался бы на первом символе, который не может трактоваться как часть числа, и просто выбрасывал бы считанное в никуда...

Comment: @Harry, w for window, см. ncurses.

Comment: @Harry wscanw - for window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanw` не является стандартной C функцией.

Смысл спецификации формата в этом вызове функции

```
scanw("%*d");
```

означает, что будет прочитано целое число (символ преобразования `d` в спецификации формата `%*d`), но оно не будет нигде сохранено (флаг `*` перед символом преобразования `d` в спецификации формата `%*d`). То есть целое число в потоке ввода пропускается (извлекается, но нигде не сохраняется).

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде бы предполагалось что такой scanw очистит поток для следующего нажатия клавиш. И еще почему тогда ch изменяется?

Comment: @CGLike Я не понял смысла вашего вопроса. ch изменяется, потому что читается в цикле.

Comment: Если после цикла использовать scanw("%*d"); то ch становится равной -1 в любом случае

Comment: @CGLike scanw и getch являются не стандартными функциями. Вы можете поискать их описание в интернет. Я не думаю, что имеет большой смысл выяснять что эти функции и представленный вами код делают.